# Python - Print only words with less than five characters

Tags: python, split, definition

This question is related to my education, with that said I wish to have any help you provide me with as detailed as possible - I dont want to copy-paste code and hand it in. :)

The task is simple - Create a definition called writeshort(txt), take a string of words, print only words that have less than five characters. Now I have completed this, but the thing is that the task specifically sais use a *definition*. I fail here.

Code without a definition, that works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

string = raw_input(”Write a few lines: ”)
txt = string.split()
result = []

for words in txt:
    if len(words) > 4:
        continue
    result.append(words)

print ', '.join(result), ”have less than five letters!”
```

Now that looks nice, and prints without any nasty [' ']. But what about the definitions?
I've tried several things, this is the lastest, but it only prints the first word with less than five letters, and ignores the rest:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

string = raw_input(”Write a few lines: ”)
txt = string.split()

def writeshort(txt):
    for txt in txt:
        if len(txt) > 4: #Yes I know its a 4, but since it counts 0...
            continue
        return txt

print writeshort(txt), "have fewer letters than five!"
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks for taking time to help me learn Python!

Comment: for txt in txt??? and len() counts from 1 not 0

Comment: But if I write a 5 it will count words that are five letters long, for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for the help everybody! I got it working! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, because the loop in `writeshort` encounters the return statement when it finds a short word and returns immediately.

If you need all the short words from `writeshort`, you'll need to *collect* them first in a list, then finally return the list. Maybe like this:

```
def writeshort(txt):
    wordlist = []
    for item in txt:
        if len(item) > 4:
            continue
        wordlist += [item] # or wordlist.append(item) as in your first snippet
    return wordlist
```

The whole function could be replaced by a one-liner and more pythonic code:

```
[word for word in txt if len(word) <= 4]
```

And you've written `for txt in txt:`, which is weird. It will do what is intended (execute for each item in the original `txt`), but `txt` would be changed to an item of the list in each iteration.

Comment: Thanks alot! I though I had to use a `[]` somewhere but it just diden't fit... And yeah I agree `txt for txt` looks wierd, but I read some other examples where they had wrote `for x in txt`, and later declare `x = txt`, figuered it did the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the `return txt`; during the `for` loop, the first time Python hits that statement, it'll return `txt` and *stop calling `writeshort` entirely*.

Why not do it like your old code, which collects them into a list and then uses that?

```
def writeshort(txt):
    result = []
    for word in txt:
        if len(word) > 4:
            continue
        result.append(word)
    return result
```

(I changed the confusing `for txt in txt` to `for word in txt`, which doesn't override the old variable named `txt`.)

Also, your comment on `if len(word) > 4` makes me think you might be a little confused about that: `len` doesn't "count 0" - you're probably thinking of indexing, which starts at 0. The reason you need `> 4` is because that checks that it's *greater than* 4, ie 5 or more. You could also say `>= 5`.

---

While we're at it, why not make your code a tad nicer?

Instead of using `continue` in your loop, you could do it a little more directly by negating the condition:

```
result = []
for word in txt:
    if len(word) < 5:
        result.append(word)
```

As an aside, this pattern of collecting things into a list is actually so common that Python has a special syntax that handles it (and some more general cases), called a list comprehension:

```
def writeshort(txt):
    return [word for word in txt if len(word) < 5]
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that! Well, we learn something new everyday. Thanks for the fast answers!

Answer (score 0):

A couple thoughts:

1) You're using txt as both the collection that you're looping over, and the current element:

```
for txt in txt:
```

This is at BEST going to be confusing. Try

```
for word in txt:
```

2) The main issue here is that you're returning from the function as soon as you find a word that's shorter than five characters. You should look at saving a list of these words, and then returning the entire list after checked every word in txt.

```
def writeshort(txt):
    shortwords = []
    for word in txt:
        if len(txt) > 4: 
            continue
        shortwords += [word]
    return shortwords
```

Comment: Should be `shortwords += [word]`, otherwise an exception will be raised when trying to append a `str` to a `list`.

Comment: Thanks for catching that.
Is this behavior specific to Python3? In Python 2.7, it will append the string as a sequence of chars, as opposed to raising an exception Still not what I meant though :)

Comment: Oh, right you are, I forgot that a `str` is also an `iterable`, and can be appended to a `list`, another `iterable`. And I don't know what would happen in Python 3.0 :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm using Python3 btw!

Comment: @AndreasBizzozero Are you sure? In Python 3 you can't write `print  writeshort(txt), "have fewer letters than five!"`, You have to write `print(writeshort(txt), "have fewer letters than five!")`.

Comment: I do `print ', '.join(writeshort(txt)), "have fewer than five letters!"` and it works nicely?

Comment: Perhaps I do use some other version, but according to komodo it sais "Python3"